# Controlling piezoelectric-actuated mirror wth arduino

Tags: arduino, laser, piezoelectricity

I would like to know where I can purchase a piezoelectric-actuated mirror device, such as those used in a single-colour laser pattern (not scanning) projector eg. the kinds used at music venues/concerts.. I'm assuming these devices reflect a single laser beam with the piezo mirror according to some coordinates/defined rotations.

Is anyone familiar with these devices? I'm not sure where to read more about them, apart form supplier websites, etc.. I would like to control my own laser projector, creating patterns etc, using an arduino for prototyping.

What other kind of device can achieve high speed movements (>120Hz) for a move-pause-move-pause... type action.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones I have seen that are intended for wide deflection angles like what you are talking about are not piezo but rather galvanic movements (like old meter movements).  There used to be a company called General Scanning somewhere in the Boston area (Watertown?) that specialized in these things.  I don't know if they are still around, but that's for you to chase down.

Comment: Thanks Olin. A follow up question... do you think it would be possible to deflect an area of much larger size... eg. the unfocused beam of a multimedia projector?

Comment: @Machu: The bigger the size the slower the movement will be due to the inertia.  If you only need something slow a mirror connected to a stepper motor would work.  Look around and see what kind of products are available.

Answer (score 1):

They're not piezo actuated. You're searching for a "galvo motor" (or "galvo scanner").

Answer (score 0):

I asked to a collegue that works with lasers, and he uses [galvanometer scanners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_projector#Galvanometer_scanners), which are in principle similar to analog instruments: two coils are driven by analog currents that determine the push/pull action of the magnetic field. Their balanced action sets the position of the rotor.

In the site of [LaserFX](http://www.laserfx.com/Works/Works3S.html), a manufacturer of these actuators, you can find some explanation about their operation:

[image]

From what I understand that brand is quite expensive and he has also bought from [this other brand](http://www.dtelectronic.cn/production.asp?ArticleID=6).

You should be able to build one yourself, but hardly you'll get nearly the same performance in terms of speed and accuracy.